# Segmentation Fault in Array and Pointer in C

Tags: c, string, curl, segmentation-fault, strcat

I am doing program with array and pointer and got this segmentation fault. Can any one explain why I have been getting this segmentation fault in this code.

My Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        char CPID[50] = "98f5b52a59aa4503999894c10bc33dca" ;
        char Uni_ID[10] = "Demo123" ;
        char *postData;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl)
        {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://avnetagent.iotconnect.io/api/2.0/agent/sync");
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
                //postData = "{\"cpId\":\""+CPID+"\",\"uniqueId\":\""+Uni_ID+"\",\"option\":{\"attribute\":false,\"setting\":false,\"protocol\":false,\"device\":false,\"sdkConfig\":false,\"rule\":false}}";
                postData = "{\"cpId\":\"";
                strcat(postData,CPID);
                strcat(postData,"\",\"uniqueId\":\"");
                strcat(postData,Uni_ID);
                strcat(postData,"\",\"option\":{\"attribute\":false,\"setting\":false,\"protocol\":false,\"device\":false,\"sdkConfig\":false,\"rule\":false}}");

                headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
                 headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData);
                /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                /* Check for errors */
                if(res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

                /* always cleanup */
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are 1) writing to memory that you are not allowed to modify and 2) writing to memory that does not belong to you.

Here

```
postData = "{\"cpId\":\"";
```

you set the pointer `postData` to point to a string literal, i.e. a constant string that you are not allowed to modify. However, you do

```
strcat(postData,CPID);
```

which will append the string `CPID` to the string literal. In other words - it will modify the string literal by overwriting its string termination character and further it will copy parts of `CPID` into the memory just after the string literal. Both operations are invalid.

What you need is to make `postData` point to memory that can be modified.

**Fix 1:**

```
char *postData;            --->   char postData[8192];

postData = "{\"cpId\":\""; --->   strcpy(postData, "{\"cpId\":\"");
```

**Fix 2:**

```
char *postData;            --->   char *postData = malloc(8192);
                                  assert(postData != NULL);

postData = "{\"cpId\":\""; --->   strcpy(postData, "{\"cpId\":\"");

return 0;                  --->   free(postData);
                                  return 0;
```

A downside of both fixes are the fixed memory size (i.e. 8192 chars). Will that always be sufficient memory for the data you want to post?

If you know the upper limit, you can set a fixed size (like I did).

If you don't know an upper limit, you have to change your code so that you can increase the allocated memory at run-time, e.g. using `realloc` (possible only for "Fix 2").

Notice that using "Fix 1" with a very high amount of memory, e.g. `char postData[8192000];` is a problem on most systems as they have a size limit for variables with automatic storage duration.

So to conclude:

If you know the upper size limit for the data to post **and** the limit is reasonable small, you can go with the simple Fix 1.

Otherwise I'll recommend fix 2.

Comment: Thank you, ;) . I tried Fix 1 that was working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
 strcat(postData,CPID);
```

the memory pointed to by `postData` is neither modifiable nor have enough space to hold concatenated string.

You need to either

- Make `postData` an array with dimention sufficient to hold the concatenated string.
- Allocate enough memory using allocator functions (`malloc()` and family) and store that pointer in `postData`.

To add, from the [`strcat()` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

> `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`
>
> *The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result.If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; [...]*

Comment: I'm new to pointer. can u please explain me or correct it in my code.

Comment: I think the answer covers all the required points. Please give it a try and come back if something does not work. Here "do-my-work-for-free" requests are frowned upon.